# Mocha Dynamic test generation in before block not getting executed

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

As suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35793665/4005379) , I tried the steps to create dynamic tests , but I see the actual test(test.getMochaTest()in my below implementation) not getting executed. What's that I'm missing here, the call on test.getMochaTest() does not get executed in the before block.

```
describe('Dynamic Tests for Mocha', async () => {
    let outcome ;
    before(async() => {
        await init().catch(() => console.error('Puppeteer environment initialization failed'));
        return collectTests().then(async(collectTests) => {
            console.info('4.Executing tests :');
            describe('Dynamic test execution', async() => {
                collectTests.forEach(async(test) => {
                    console.info(`\tModule under test : ${test.name}`);

        // impl. of test.getMochaTest() DOES NOT get executed. 

                    it(test.name, async() => outcome = await test.getMochaTest().catch(async () => {
                        console.error(`error while executing test:\t${test.name}`);
                    }));
                });
            }) ;
        });
    });

    after(async () => {
        console.info('5. Exiting tests...');
        await HelperUtils.delay(10000).then(async () => { await browser.close(); });
        console.log('executing after block');
    });

    it('placeholder',  async() =>  {
        await
        console.log('place holder hack - skip it');
    });

});
```

Array of tests is returned here :

```
async function collectTests():Promise<Array<ITest>> {
    console.info('3.Collecting tests to execute ...');
    testArray = new Array<ITest>();
    const login:ITest = new SLogin('Login Check');
    testArray.push(login);
    
    return testArray;
}
```

The below implementation of `getMochaTest` in SLogin -> does not get executed .

```
export default class SLogin extends BTest implements ITest {
    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }
    async getMochaTest():Promise<Mocha.Func> {
        return async () => {
            console.log('Running Login check');
            expect(true).to.equal(true);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually invoking the test.

Calling `test.getMochaTest()` only returns the async test function in a Promise, it doesn't execute it. So your `catch` block is catching errors while *obtaining* the function, not while *executing* it.

Breaking it out across multiple lines will hopefully make things clearer.

Here's what your code sample does. Notice it never executes the returned test function:

```
it(test.name, async () => {
    const testFn = await test.getMochaTest().catch(() => 
        console.error(`error while ***obtaining*** test: \t${test.name}`));

    // oops - testFn never gets called!
});
```

And here's a corrected version where the test actually gets called:

```
it(test.name, async () => {
    const testFn = await test.getMochaTest().catch(() => 
        console.error(`error while ***obtaining*** test: \t${test.name}`));

    const outcome = await testFn().catch(() => 
        console.error(`error while ***executing*** test: \t${test.name}`));
});
```

Note: I wrote it that way with `await` and `catch()` to better match the format of your code sample. However, it's worth pointing out that it mixes `async`/`await` and `Promise` syntax. More idiomatic would be to catch errors with a `try/catch` block when using `async`/`await`.

Comment: @thanks for pointing that out . However it complains with `node:4164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: testFn is not a function`

Comment: => thanks ! that worked, fixed that by changing the declaration `const testFn` to `let testFn` before the describe. Also its good to use `for..of `instead of `forEach` loop , while executing test in sequence.